# need writing function to find percentage from total in pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pivot-table, analytics

For example this table:

```
list_1=[['A',10,42,12,64],
        ['B',24,11,62,95],
       ['C',14,78,20,112]]
labels=['Class','Amount_1','Amount_2','Amount_3','Total']
df=pd.DataFrame(list_1,columns=labels)
df
```

```
Class   Amount_1    Amount_2    Amount_3    Total
0   A   10            42         12          64
1   B   24            11         62          95
2   C   14            78         20          112
```

I need write function to get this table (amount rate from total):

```
Class    Amount_1   Amount_2    Amount_3            
A       0.156250    0.656250    0.187500
B       0.252632    0.115789    0.652632
C       0.125000    0.696429    0.178571
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize

df[["Amount_1", "Amount_2", "Amount_3"]]=normalize(df[["Amount_1", "Amount_2", "Amount_3"]], axis=1, norm="l1")
```

Outputs:

```py
  Class  Amount_1  Amount_2  Amount_3  Total
0     A  0.156250  0.656250  0.187500     64
1     B  0.247423  0.113402  0.639175     95
2     C  0.125000  0.696429  0.178571    112
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
df.update(df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains('Amount')].div(df.Total,0))
df
Out[41]: 
  Class  Amount_1  Amount_2  Amount_3  Total
0     A  0.156250  0.656250  0.187500     64
1     B  0.252632  0.115789  0.652632     95
2     C  0.125000  0.696429  0.178571    112
```

Comment: Maybe `df.filter(like='Amount')` instead of `df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains('Amount')]`

Comment: Yes this right output, but if you can write function as UDF or lambda ?

Comment: @Galat why use lambda ,...'

Comment: Because this sulution include df.columns.str.contains('Amount') and only suitable for this example

Comment: If columns with a different name this solution not work

Comment: @Galat your columns have the different names

Comment: Ok, in really table I have 20 columns names of countries(USA,Canada, France......) So this solution doesn't work